# convertir DateFormat en int en Java

Tags: java, date, integer

quiero sacar la fecha actual en un único numero, de forma que luego pueda compararlo con otras fechas con el mismo formato. Mi problema viene cuando saco la fecha, en forma de string, e intento convertirlo en int. Aunque el string contiene SOLO numeros me sale una excepción y no me convierte el numero y no entiendo porque.

```
    import java.util.*; import java.text.DateFormat; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Your code here!
                        DateFormat hoy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                Date date = new Date();
                String hoyS =hoy.format(date).toString();
                int hoyf;
                
        System.out.println(hoyS);
                hoyf= Integer.valueOf(hoyS);
    } }
```

Comment: Hola siempre agrega el error que se produce por favor, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tamaño máximo de un entero es `2147483647`, tiene 10 dígitos de longitud.

La fecha en formato `yyyyMMddHHmmss` tiene 14 digitos, no cabe en un entero.

La solución es usar un `long` en lugar de `int`.

```
long hoyf;
hoyf = Long.valueOf(hoyS);
```